# set and retrieve values of form field including checkbox in jquery with ajax

Tags: jquery

I have a simple form where there are 2 text boxes and 2 checkboxes..

I am using jquery with ajax to retrieve those form field values and set it to ajax post request and trying to retrieveit in servlet.

I get all values of form except the selected checbox values..

Here is what I tried :

user.jsp

```
Select a City : 
<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="usa" value="la">LA
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="usa" value="ny">Newyork
```

my Jquery :

```
 $("#save").click(function(){

          var citiesUsa = new Array();

          alert("button clicked");
          $("input:checkbox[name=usa]:checked").each(function()
                  {

              citiesUsa.push($(this).val());

              });

          $.post("UserServlet",
          {

            name: $('#fname').val(),
            country : $('#country').val(),

            usa :  citiesUsa,



          },
          function(data,status){
           // alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
           alert("success");
          });
        });

    });
```

And in servlet I try to retrieve the checkbox values like this :

```
System.out.println("request.getParameter(usa)"+" "+request.getParameterValues("usa"));
```

I have tried many thing bu the checkbox value returns to null  ..

please guide..

Comment: try console.log(citiesUsa) before post and check whether there are any values in it

Comment: if u are having only 2 checkboxes, why cant u use $("input:checkbox[name=usa]:checked").val() directly instead of looping in an each function

Comment: then how will i retrieve multiple checked values..what if both the checkboxes are checked?

Comment: what did console.log() do. is it showing anything?

Comment: when i did console.log("console.log"+" "+citiesUsa); before the $.post it printed nothing..not even the message 'console.log'..but when i tried to do alert the inintially it showed la and then la,ny